# Delete specific column if all values are NA in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've got a database query running from R which can have multiple columns filled with NA, some of these columns I need further down the line but one specific column can be dropped if all values are NA.

I usually use purrr::discard(~all(is.na(.))) to drop the columns which are all NA, but since this dataframe can contain multiple columns with NA where I only want to remove one I'm struggling to make this specific to the column in a tidyverse solution.

I've currently got this workaround:

```
  if(sum(is.na(Orders$Originator)) == nrow(Orders)) {
    
    Orders <- Orders %>%
      select(-Originator)
    
  }
```

But it would improve the readability if I can have this in a tidyverse solution. Hope someone can be of help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,NA),
  y = NA,
  z = c(3,4,5)
)
```

Here column `y` is the target column to check if `all` `is.na`. Your `if` and `else` will be contained in curly braces. The braces will suppress the pipe from using the first argument in a function. Note the `else` will keep your data frame in the pipe if the condition is false.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  { if (all(is.na(.$y))) select(., -y) else . }
```

**Output**

```
   x z
1  1 3
2  2 4
3 NA 5
```

Comment: Didn't know we could integrate functions like that. Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

The canonical tidyverse way to address this problem would be to make use of a predicate function used within `select(where(...))` and combine this with selection by variable name.

First we could write a custom predicate function to use in `where` which selects only columns that contain only `NA`s.

```r
# custom predicate function
all_na <- function(x) {
  all(is.na(x))
}
```

We can use this function together with a boolean expression saying we **don't** want to `select` `y` if (read AND `&`) it is `all_na`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,NA),
  y = NA,
  z = c(3,4,5)
)

df %>% 
  select(!(y & where(all_na)))
#>    x z
#> 1  1 3
#> 2  2 4
#> 3 NA 5
```

To check whether this is really working let's redefine `y` so that it contains not only `NA`s and we will see that this time it's not deselected:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,NA),
  y = c(1,2,NA),
  z = c(3,4,5)
)

df2 %>% 
  select(!(y & where(all_na)))
#>    x  y z
#> 1  1  1 3
#> 2  2  2 4
#> 3 NA NA 5
```

Instead of a custom function we can use a lambda function inside `where`:

```r
df %>% 
  select(!(y & where(~ all(is.na(.x)))))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

In the larger tidyverse we could also use `purrr::lmap_at` and select `y` with the `.at` argument and then create a lambda function saying if `all(is.na(.x))` then use an empty `list()` (= drop the column) otherwise keep the column `.x`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  lmap_at("y", ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) list() else .x)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3
#> 2     2     4
#> 3    NA     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to mix selection by name (i.e. only specific column) and by logical. Both can be done very well separately in tidyverse (use tidy selectors or `where`), but I am not sure how to combine them!

So here is a dirty solution that doesn't use either:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,NA),
  y = NA,
  y2 = NA,
  z = c(3,4,5)
)

df %>% 
  select(-which(colnames(.)=="y" & sapply(., \(x) all(is.na(x)))))
#>    x y2 z
#> 1  1 NA 3
#> 2  2 NA 4
#> 3 NA NA 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Problem with this solution is that if you add a column, for example a with all NA values that gets removed too. I have more columns which can contain complete NA, but I only want to remove one.